# Order by column when view result from cursor :to_grid :=vCur;

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

here is how I view output result from cursor(toad) but I'd like to order
by some column of this output result, how can I do it in code below
without changing procedure itself:

```
declare
 vCur reports.rep_type;
begin
 testCursor(999, vCur);
  :to_grid :=vCur;
 end;
```

thanks in advance, 
S

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Toad 12.1.0.22, and what I do is: `right click on the grid --> Check Memory Sorting`.

Then you can sort on the columns like you normally would. It works well for smaller data sets. I have experienced issues with larger data sets (thousands of rows).